# Slow wi-fi speed when a wired machine is on

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have a wi-fi router T-Link TL-WR1043ND with default firmware 3.13.6 Build 110712 Rel.33710n. And 2 machines, connected to it:

1. Linux laptop by wi-fi
2. Windows XP by a wired connection.

When the windows machine is on - even with 0 network activity: I checked by the task manager - the speed of Linux connection drops to 0,8 Mbps. But when I turn the windows machine off it rises up to 4,45 Mbps.

What can it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Check for ROOTKIT (try GMER or MBAM).
- Make sure you have a decent two-way firewall (Zonealarm Free) for Windows.

How long ago was your Linux and Windows installed? Are both fully updated and legal?

Comment: I checked with GMER, the system is clear. Linux is from December 2011, Windows - June 2010. Win is illegal. But I suspect, there is something with the router here.

Comment: Were you able to apply all patches? I understand that in systems like your, WinXP nags if system is unpatched. For precaution of leaving any port open, I would reinstall Windows. What is the Linux? Ubuntu? Mint? flavor+version, please. Enable the GUFW and monitor logs.

Comment: WinXP is pathed up to service pack 3. Linux is Slackware 13.37. ok, will do.

Comment: What is the firewall and antivirus on your XP system? Also, if you can post GMER log (especially SERVICES), HijackThis, RunAlyzer or Spybot Search & Destroy log for your WinXP. It looks as something is hooking into WinSock (usually trojans). RegAlyzer also lets you see several other hidden registries also. What are the Task Scheduled? 

http://www.safer-networking.org/dl/products/regalyzer/

Comment: No, I think you are suggesting a wrong direction. I am sure, that I don't have any trojans, making unnecessary traffic. Cause I oped the ADSL modem statistics, that must be independent of any trojans, closed all the programs, except browser. And it showed about 1 Mb sent and 40 Kb received in 5 minutes. Maybe, I should try to update the router firmware?

Comment: Ok, after upgrading the firmware it works fine.

Comment: Or, I was going to suggest if you are running P2P or bulk downloading program on Windows (Shareaza, Vuze) then it could explain this behavior. Glad your flashing the router worked.

Answer (score 1):

I've a few things I would suspect:

First, look at the condition of the cable. If it's really beat up, it may just be no good any more.

Second, while you're looking at the cable, read it. It'll say on it a bunch of things, but somewhere on it there will be a CatX rating (X will be 3, 5, 5e, or 6, most likely).

Third, if you run the speed test and get slow numbers (and you've concluded none of the above is applicable), try moving it to a different port on your router.